# Getting "Prelude.read: no parse" error when using detailed-0.9 tests with cabal

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, cabal

I tried to follow [this guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites) in order to write some tests for a Haskell package using the `detailed-0.9` test type. The cabal file is

```
Name:           bar
Version:        1.0
License:        BSD3
Cabal-Version:  >= 1.10
Build-Type:     Simple

Library
    exposed-modules:     Foo
    build-depends:       base >=4.9 && <4.10
    default-language:    Haskell2010

Test-Suite test-bar
    type:       detailed-0.9
    test-module: Bar
    build-depends: base, Cabal >= 1.9.2
    default-language:    Haskell2010
```

and Bar.hs is

```
module Bar ( tests ) where

import Distribution.TestSuite

tests :: IO [Test]
tests = return [ Test succeeds, Test fails ]
  where
    succeeds = TestInstance
        { run = return $ Finished Pass
        , name = "succeeds"
        , tags = []
        , options = []
        , setOption = \_ _ -> Right succeeds
        }
    fails = TestInstance
        { run = return $ Finished $ Fail "Always fails!"
        , name = "fails"
        , tags = []
        , options = []
        , setOption = \_ _ -> Right fails
        }
```

However, when I run the tests with

```
cabal configure --enable-tests
cabal build
cabal test
```

I get

```
Preprocessing test suite 'test-bar' for bar-1.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( dist/build/test-barStub/test-barStub-tmp/test-barStub.hs, dist/build/test-barStub/test-barStub-tmp/Main.dyn_o )
Linking dist/build/test-barStub/test-barStub ...
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test-bar: RUNNING...
Prelude.read: no parse
```

This also happens with the code from [this repository](https://github.com/michaxm/test-detailed-example).

Using `strace cabal test` I managed to see that the last file that cabal tries to open is `dist/test/cabal-test-1804289383846930886.log`, which does not exist. Creating the file does not help.

Is the `detailed-0.9` test type still experimental? Should I use `exitcode-stdio-1.0` instead?

GHC version: 8.0.1
cabal version: 1.24.0.0

EDIT:
The error persists even if I set `tests = return []` in `Bar.hs`.

Comment: Your code (plus a stub Foo.hs) works for me.  I've seen that error happen when the test program crashes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that too.

Comment: This works fine for me, using the same ghc and cabal. Did you try `cabal clean` before building?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I tried to run `cabal clean`, but it made no difference. Is there any configuration that could interfere with this? Or any package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with dynamic linkage. Cabal could not find the .so of the test. In my case, adding a link to `dist/build/bar-1.0-1l0Xa8pRO0dDWU0quwEdrS-test-bar.test/libHSbar-1.0-1l0Xa8pRO0dDWU0quwEdrS-test-bar.test-ghc8.0.1.so` solved the problem, but the filename probably changes.

The alternative is to use `cabal configure --enable-tests --disable-shared` when configuring the package (I use `--enable-shared` implicitly in my cabal config). Or I can hack a script which sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the proper value before calling `cabal test`.

EDIT: there is already a [pull request on github](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/3527).